# SSIS script tasks can't compile because of missing dlls

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dll, ssis

We rolled out SSIS-Packages to our customers, that include script tasks, which reference 5 dll files in the folder:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework
\v4.0**

On the target server, there doesnt seem to bee .dll files in this folder, only xml files. Therefore the script tasks can not compile.

Would it suffice to add these missing .dlls to the folder to solve this problem?

Comment: yes you need to add those .dll files (specially like 3rd party .dll's added from nuget) to the GAC in the target server and it will work

Comment: I've added the missing .dll-Files there, but it still couldn't compile. :( Any other ideas? These are no 3rd party dll's, they belong to the .NET-Framework. (e.g. System.Data.dll)

Comment: You might find you can do what you need without script tasks, though it's probably too late to redesign.

Comment: I solved the problem. I copied the .dll files from my system to the production system including the "RedistList" folder. Then it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A typical SSIS script task references looks like this.

[image]

The top 2 references are not in NETFramework folder.